# How to start a new Activity after completing 2 AsyncTask From an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my Main `Activity` Having two different `AsyncTask` Running in background.

after AsyncTask its start the new `Activity`.

this Working fine

**Main Activity**---->>>>**New Activity**

**Problem:**

but my Problem is Without Completing the two `AsyncTasks`, it Moving to New `Activity`

Both Task must be complete then only go to New `Activity`.

Help me how to Solve this.

```
AsyncCallWSfor1 task1 = new AsyncCallWSfor1();
                // Call execute
                task1.execute();


                AsyncCallWSfor2 task2 = new AsyncCallWSfor2();
                // Call execute
                task2.execute();

        Toast.makeText(sign_in.this, "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivivty.this,NewActvity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: write code in post execute of asyctask to start new activity

Comment: post Execute ok, Both Async task having Postexecute where i have to add

Comment: you first need to learn what AsyncTask does. and make an algorithm to wait for both tasks complete.

Comment: Maintain two boolean for two asynctask . Assign true them onPostMethod and check both boolean is true thn navigate.

Comment: On second task I guess. As the execution of tasks would be serial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will definately solve your problem do something like this

```
  //create variable for your activity or fragment
            Boolean isTask1Completed=false,isTask2Completed=false;

            //on post execute of task 1
            isTask1Completed = true;
            if(isTask1Completed&&isTask2Completed){
                //start activity here
            }

            //on post execute of task 2
            isTask2Completed = true;

            if(isTask1Completed&&isTask2Completed){
                //start activity here
            }
```

Comment: this is what u are looking for, except synchronisation problem.

Comment: this is for when both tasks are started and we have to find out both are completed or not if yes then go forward

Comment: on a second thought since `onPostExecute` is called in ui, synchronisation wont be a problem.

Comment: i didn't get you what exactly you want to say.
by the way according to the question user want to complete both of tasks first.

Comment: if i am doing like this ,Any problem occur in UI ? @bluebrain

Comment: @Kumar, nah it is ok this way.

Comment: Ok Iam trying in my Code

Comment: dont ask for votes see the help center for the usage policy.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why can't you try both method using one Asynchronous Task**

```
        private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();

                        }


                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                          String result="";
                         if(url.equals("m1"))
                            {

                                <!--Method one-->
                                 result="first";
                            }else
                            {

                                 <!--Method Two-->
                                  result="second";

                            }

                                return result;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                              if(result.equals("second")
                               {
                                <!--Start activity-->
                               }else
                               {
                                 <!--Call Asynchronous task with second method-->
                              }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: because its data fetch  from Web service two Different methods

Answer (score 1):

Use some simple checkers

```
boolean first = false;
boolean second = false;
```

and

```
AsyncTask1
onPostExecute() { 
  first = true;
  if (first && second) startActivity();
} 

AsyncTask2
onPostExecute() { 
  second = true; 
  if (first && second) startActivity();
}
```

Comment: on a second thought, volatile is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a boolean variable

```
boolean firstCompleted=false;
```

In `onPostExecute(-)` of `AsyncCallWSfor1` make it as `true`

```
firstCompleted=true;
```

And in `onPostExecute(-)` of `AsyncCallWSfor2` start new Activity

```
if(firstCompleted){
   Toast.makeText(sign_in.this, "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivivty.this,NewActvity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: this makes tasks serial, he could combine two tasks into one.

Comment: but here first task fails 2 task Will not Execute ?

Comment: if  2 Task is Completed ,it will go to new Activity know, Even first task is not Completed!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code

> Toast.makeText(sign_in.this, "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivivty.this,NewActvity.class);
>      startActivity(intent);
>        finish()

in your..

> AsyncCallWSfor2 task2 = new AsyncCallWSfor2();

post method it will run fine....

Answer (score 0):

Asynctasks are executed *serially*. You should put it on postExecute of the second task.

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: this seems to be a comment to me. it is OK to start two tasks serially, execution will be parallel.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the documentation says. >When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with Callbacks.
You start your (i think) API Client or something and run a query.
When it starts, it will run the request in a new Thread and once it has finished loading, it will call back to the activity which has startet the request.

On this way you can be sure, tasks will be done one after another.

Activity -> new ApiClient() -> execute(url, parameters) -> new Thread() -> run Query -> Call ApiClientCallback -> Activity receives response -> do whatever is necessary

Have a look here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers